# DNN - getting user roles in javascript

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke

I have an app in DotNetNuke.  I would like to retrieve the list of user roles in header javascript, and check to see if it has "Administrators" role.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
using DotNetNuke.Common;
using System.Collections;
using DotNetNuke.Security.Roles;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var RoleController = new RoleController();
var UserRoles = new List<RoleInfo>();

//for dnn 7.3 and lower
if (Globals.DataBaseVersion.Major < 7 || (Globals.DataBaseVersion.Major == 7 && Globals.DataBaseVersion.Minor < 3))
{
    UserRoles = RoleController.GetPortalRoles(PortalId).Cast<RoleInfo>().ToList();
}
else
{
    //for dnn 7.3 and higher
    UserRoles = RoleController.GetRoles(PortalId).ToList();
}

//convert the list to a json array
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(UserRoles.Select(x => x.RoleName));

//send the json to a client side function
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "allUserRoles", "setUserRoles('" + json + "')", true);
```

And the client side function. The variable `json` now is an Array with all the roles.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setUserRoles(roles) {
        var json = JSON.parse(roles);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            console.log(json[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```